# Installation of Mongodb from an AWS Elastic Beastalk php instance

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Does anyone know how to star a Mongodb volume from a AWS Elastic Beanstalk php instance? I'm experiencing problems with SSH connection when trying to set it up on putty. Any ideas or tutorials around? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elastic Beanstalk is intended to be used for auto-scaling application server tier.  If you want to use Mongo, you're going to have to manually set up one or more EC2 instances and then connect to them from your application that runs atop Elastic Beanstalk.